# i want to store some data in "EverNote" through our app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, evernote

i want to store some data in "EverNote"  through our app either (image or text or both).

I googled, i got some guidance like EverNote SDK and i got the EverNoteCounter Sample also(When i run this, when i click getCount button it shows an alert message "Could not authenticate").
I generated the developer token also.

But i unable to create the consumerKey,consumerSecret. And also i did not find how to store our data to evernote from our app.

I got some links like [this](http://discussion.evernote.com/topic/27738-getting-started-posting-image-to-evernote-from-ios-app/) one

but when i go through that link it says( HTTP method GET is not supported by this URL)

I able to authenticate with the EVERNOTE and i able to get the number of notebooks in that Account.

I am using sqllite in my app. i am using one folder for images. Sqllite have the images links info.

How to store the data.

I used the following code to authenticate and to get the count

```
    - (IBAction)retrieveUserNameAndNoteCount:(id)sender
{
    // Create local reference to shared session singleton
    EvernoteSession *session = [EvernoteSession sharedSession];
    [session authenticateWithViewController:self completionHandler:^(NSError *error) {
        // Authentication response is handled in this block
        if (error || !session.isAuthenticated) {
            // Either we couldn't authenticate or something else went wrong - inform the user
            if (error) {
                NSLog(@"Error authenticating with Evernote service: %@", error);
            }
            if (!session.isAuthenticated) {
                NSLog(@"User could not be authenticated.");
            }
            UIAlertView *alert = [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" 
                                                             message:@"Could not authenticate" 
                                                            delegate:nil 
                                                   cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" 
                                                   otherButtonTitles:nil] autorelease];
            [alert show];
        } else {
            // We're authenticated!
            EvernoteUserStore *userStore = [EvernoteUserStore userStore];
            // Retrieve the authenticated user as an EDAMUser instance
            [userStore getUserWithSuccess:^(EDAMUser *user) {
                // Set usernameField (UILabel) text value to username
                [usernameField setText:[user username]];
                // Retrieve total note count and display it
                [self countAllNotesAndSetTextField];                
            } failure:^(NSError *error) {
                NSLog(@"Error retrieving authenticated user: %@", error);
            }];
        } 
    }];    
}

- (void)countAllNotesAndSetTextField
{
    // Allow access to this variable within the block context below (using __block keyword)
    __block int noteCount = 0;

    EvernoteNoteStore *noteStore = [EvernoteNoteStore noteStore];
    [noteStore listNotebooksWithSuccess:^(NSArray *notebooks) {
        for (EDAMNotebook *notebook in notebooks) {
            if ([notebook guid]) {
                EDAMNoteFilter *filter = [[EDAMNoteFilter alloc] init];
                [filter setNotebookGuid:[notebook guid]];
                [noteStore findNoteCountsWithFilter:filter withTrash:NO success:^(EDAMNoteCollectionCounts *counts) {
                    if (counts) {

                        // Get note count for the current notebook and add it to the displayed total
                        NSNumber *notebookCount = (NSNumber *)[[counts notebookCounts] objectForKey:[notebook guid]];
                        noteCount = noteCount + [notebookCount intValue];
                        NSString *noteCountString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", noteCount];
                        [noteCountField setText:noteCountString];
                    }
                } failure:^(NSError *error) {
                    NSLog(@"Error while retrieving note counts: %@", error);
                }];
            }
        }        
    } failure:^(NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error while retrieving notebooks: %@", error);
    }];
}
```

Please suggest me the links or give me the guidance

Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 2):

Developer token is to be used when you only need to access your own account. To get a consumer key/secret, go here : http://dev.evernote.com/documentation/cloud/ .

If you are using iOS, https://github.com/evernote/evernote-sdk-ios has a sample app that you can use once you have a consumer key and secret.

In general, there is a lot of information on dev.evernote.com.

All SDKs are located at https://github.com/evernote

Getting started guide for iOS : http://blog.evernote.com/tech/2012/05/24/evernote-sdk-integration-ios/

Comment: yeah.. i followed those links and also i got EverNoteTest sample also.. There it giving an error says "EDAMUserException: unknown"  authentication fails. I given the consumer key and secret key  also@Mustafa

Comment: What host name are you using? You should use sandbox.evernote.com for development. If you are still seeing an issue,
I would recommend posting your issue here : http://discussion.evernote.com/forum/61-evernote-for-developers/

Comment: i am using sand box account.  Now i posted the question on formus. Thanks for your answer  @Mustafa

Answer (score 0):

Did you solved it? If not, i did the following to get it work:

1. download and include sdk
2. get consumerKey and secret (if you want to access notes too, then
   instead of basic you should request for full access, http://dev.evernote.com/documentation/cloud/ top right corner)
3. Add the URLType entry in info.plist ("Modify your application's main
   plist file" chapter https://github.com/evernote/evernote-sdk-ios)
4. Copy the session init code (filled with consumer key and secret, the hostname should be left unchanged) and implement the two application delegate specific code
5. An (on-screen) viewcontroller should be passed on authenticating the user to `authenticateWithViewController` method, f.e. the appdelegate's rootViewController

Study this pages to understand the model hierarchy used by Evernote:

http://dev.evernote.com/documentation/cloud/chapters/data_structure.php
http://dev.evernote.com/documentation/reference/Types.html

Image could be stored as EDAMResource (Resource) in the field `data` and text as EDAMNote (Note) in the field `content`. Both is handled by Evernote SDK's `EvernoteNoteStore` object.